# Wordpress rewrite url to index.php

Tags: wordpress, url, mod-rewrite, indexing, url-rewriting

Inside my .htaccess file, my default code is like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

What I want to do is when I open **mydomain.com** it will redirect me to **mydomain.com/?page_id=2** (but the url remain as **mydomain.com** ). How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put this in your .HTACCESS file:

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteRule ^$ /?page_id=2 [L]

**EDIT:**

Also you can set this from your Wordpress administration page: Go to Settings -> Reading and at "Front page displays" set as  "A static page (select below)" and select from the dropdown list of "Front page:" your page.

Comment: You're welcome! If you have any other questions, please do not hesitate to contact me!